# Whenever i run the following code i get 'great password' as output irrespective of the input

Tags: c

This program asks the user for a password. It requires to test whether their password has an uppercase letter, lowercase letter, and a digit. If it does, the program says the great password. If not, it says choose another password.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {

    // This part takes input from the user

    int i;
    int hasupper, haslower, hasdigit;
    char password[20];
    printf("eneter a password not more then eight characters long: \n");

    scanf("%s", password);

    // This part executes the loop to check the elements of the input.

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(password); i++) {
        if (isupper(password[i])) {
            hasupper = 1;
            continue;
        }

        if (islower(password[i])) {
            haslower = 1;
            continue;
        }

        if (isdigit(password[i])) {
            hasdigit = 1;
        }
    }

    // This part shows the outcome

    if ((hasdigit) && (haslower) && (hasupper)) {
        printf("great password\n");
    } else {
        printf("choose another password please\n");
    }
}
```

Now, whenever I run my program I see *great password* on the screen as output for whatever input I give.

Comment: Hint: be safer with `scanf("%19s", password);`

Comment: [The way gcc compiles this](https://godbolt.org/z/B6cvx3) is quite hilarious.  It seems to know that `hasupper` and friends are uninitialized and therefore could be nonzero, so it skips all the actual tests and just prints "great password" unconditionally.  The string "choose another password please" doesn't even appear in the compiled program!  Yet, with all this cleverness, it doesn't bother to *warn* the programmer that uninitialized variables are being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your helper variables are **uninitialized** and therefore untrustworthy (besides causing UB)

```
// int hasupper, haslower, hasdigit;
int hasupper = 0, haslower = 0, hasdigit = 0;
```